# Magento2 Problem with displayed price exclusing tax

Tags: magento2, taxes

I don´t know where else I can ask for help.

I have one Shop with two stores and store views. (M 2.1.5)
The 1st is for regular customers. The price is shown including tax everywhere and everything is fine.

The 2nd store is for wholesaler and the price in the frontend is supposed to be displayed excluding tax. Tax is added at the end on the check out.
Here the problems appear.

The Tax-settings in the configuration for this store are all "Excluding tax" (Shopping Cart display, Price Display Settings, Orders, invoice, credit memo display settings)

In the wholesale shop on the product page the price is still shown including tax while the shopping cart shows the tax excluding tax.

I deactivated all extensions on this store to be shure that those don´t cause the problem.

Does anybody have an idea why the price on the product page is still shown including tax?
Thanks a lot! Don´t know what else to do!

Simon

Answer (score 1):

I've been having a similar problem. In the end managed to get it to work, but I'm not entire sure why this fixed it (or more why it was not working before), but you can certainly try:

- I removed/commented out the entire `sales_display` section in my `app/etc/config.local.php` file.
- Set the settings again on the `Default Config` and both store-views.
- Finally I flushed the cache and my pdf invoices started to acknowledge their individual store-view settings.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your store configuration. Maybe some configuration was setup wrong.

- make sure you are using correct scope when you change any config.
- navigate to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax in admin.
  Please check Calculation Settings section. For most of cases you no need to change this section.
  For example **Catalog Prices** with **Including Tax** means you have entered product prices with taxes already.

Answer (score 0):

At the end (and after a long time) I found out that a 3rd party component caused this all. They said that it is not connected at first but it was.

When I deactivated it, everything was fine. It was magecomp hide price this by far the most incompetent support. They don´t even know how to deactivate an extension in magento correctly..

So this is solved.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be late regarding to the original post, but we had a similar problem this week with Magento 2.3 and wanted to help those who might be having the same issue.

As Nicholas said, you first need to change the price you want to display (including or excluding tax) but you also have to refresh at least these cache types (via the admin interface):

- Configuration (Tag "CONFIG")
- Page Cache (Tag "FPC")

Then, all prices should be displayed as wanted.

Hope this helps.